# adding jquery to react starter kit

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack, react-starter-kit

I'm new to Javascript world and starting some to create a simple React Project
I started With [React Starter Kit](https://www.reactstarterkit.com/) and added my first module whch is a simple upload file:

UploadFile.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import FormData from 'form-data';
import $ from 'jquery';

class UploadPanel extends Component {
  state = {
    file:'',
  };
  uploadSelectedFile() {

    // Add the uploaded image content to the form data collection
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("image", this.state.file);
    data.append("temp", 'temp');
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "rest/dicom/upload",
      xhr: function () {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        return myXhr;
      },
      cache: false,
      data: data,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (data) {
        alert('file sent');
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (data) {
        alert('error');
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }
  handleFileChange(e){
    let file = e.target.files;
    if(file.length>0)
      this.setState({file: file});
    else
      this.setState({file: ''});
  }

  render() {
    //return <p> hi this is a test </p>
    //var createItem = function (item) {
    //  return <li key={item.id}>{item.text}</li>;
    //};

    return <form onSubmit={this.uploadSelectedFile()}>
      <input type="file" name="image" id="image" value={this.state.file} onChange={this.handleFileChange}/>
      <input type="submit" value="ارسال"  disabled={this.state.file!=''}/>
    </form>;
  }
}


export default UploadPanel;
```

but when i open the page, the compile (in the server) gives the following error:

```
TypeError: _jquery2.default.ajax is not a function
at UploadPanel.uploadSelectedFile (D:\Projects\Behyaar\BOIS\ReactDashboardClient\build\webpack:\src\components\bois\UploadDicom\UploadPanel.js:24:7)
at UploadPanel.render (D:\Projects\Behyaar\BOIS\ReactDashboardClient\build\webpack:\src\components\bois\UploadDicom\UploadPanel.js:59:33)
at ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (D:\Projects\Behyaar\BOIS\ReactDashboardClient\node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:587:34)
at ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponent (D:\Projects\Behyaar\BOIS\ReactDashboardClient\node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:607:32)
at wrapper [as _renderValidatedComponent] (D:\Projects\Behyaar\BOIS\ReactDashboardClient\node_modules\react\lib\ReactPerf.js:66:21)
at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (D:\Projects\Behyaar\BOIS\ReactDashboardClient\node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:220:30)
at wrapper [as mountComponent] (D:\Projects\Behyaar\BOIS\ReactDashboardClient\node_modules\react\lib\ReactPerf.js:66:21)
at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (D:\Projects\Behyaar\BOIS\ReactDashboardClient\node_modules\react\lib\ReactReconciler.js:37:35)
at ReactDOMComponent.ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren (D:\Projects\Behyaar\BOIS\ReactDashboardClient\node_modules\react\lib\ReactMultiChild.js:241:44)
at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup (D:\Projects\Behyaar\BOIS\ReactDashboardClient\node_modules\react\lib\ReactDOMComponent.js:591:32)
at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent (D:\Projects\Behyaar\BOIS\ReactDashboardClient\node_modules\react\lib\ReactDOMComponent.js:479:29)
at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (D:\Projects\Behyaar\BOIS\ReactDashboardClient\node_modules\react\lib\ReactReconciler.js:37:35)
at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (D:\Projects\Behyaar\BOIS\ReactDashboardClient\node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:225:34)
at wrapper [as mountComponent] (D:\Projects\Behyaar\BOIS\ReactDashboardClient\node_modules\react\lib\ReactPerf.js:66:21)
at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (D:\Projects\Behyaar\BOIS\ReactDashboardClient\node_modules\react\lib\ReactReconciler.js:37:35)
at ReactDOMComponent.ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren (D:\Projects\Behyaar\BOIS\ReactDashboardClient\node_modules\react\lib\ReactMultiChild.js:241:44)
```

can anyone help?
why it wants to run a client side code in the server?

Answer (score 2):

In your `render` function, you've made a slight mistake with the syntax (one that I think catches everyone out in React to begin with, especially if they're coming from other frameworks). Look at this line:

```
return <form onSubmit={this.uploadSelectedFile()}> ... </form>
```

You have brackets at the end of your function name - in other words, you're calling the function every time the `render` function runs, including on the server!

The best way to demonstrate is to translate the JSX to what JavaScript will actually get run:

```
return React.createElement("form", { onSubmit: this.uploadSelectedFile() });
```

You're setting the `onSubmit` property to the *return value* of `this.uploadSelectedFile`, rather than the function itself.

There's two things you need to fix - first, remove the brackets from the end of the previously mentioned statement. The second thing is a little less obvious - as you're using ES6 classes, [you need to be explicit about binding your functions to the correct `this` value](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding):

```
class UploadPanel extends Component {
    ...
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.uploadSelectedFile = this.uploadSelectedFile.bind(this);
        this.handleFileChange = this.handleFileChange.bind(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

[There's also more elegant ways of doing this with arrow functions if you're using the `stage-0` Babel preset.](http://www.ian-thomas.net/autobinding-react-and-es6-classes/)

Hopefully that cleared things up for you a bit!